# PHP decoding square brackets href attr to html file

Tags: php

Saving an **html** the decodes square brackets.

```
//My STRing     
$teaserTest = "<a href='[CLICK_URL]'><strong>testgerr</strong></a>";
//Calling save function
saveFile($teaserTest);    
//Save function
function saveFile($stringToAdd){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadHTML('<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>'.$stringToAdd.'</body></html>');

$doc->saveHTMLFile("Campaigns/test.html");
}
```

file resaults `<a href="%5BCLICK_URL%5D">`

im trying to keep the"[" decoded.

Comment: You may want to try `loadHtml($yourHtmlString,LIBXML_NOENT)` - that should stop substituting some entities.

Answer (score 1):

```
[]  brackets are special chars in url
```

which is specified in following [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) It is important for the ip address for `example: http://[::1]/example/`

That because it is good to encoding. But if you have a special approach use a different pattern for it.